# Angular 2 CRUD application

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a CRUD application with Angular 2 and I am not yet familiar with Angular. I have created a `Hello World` app with the help of [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

But now I want to create an application using Angular 2 with MVC 5. I've tried many things but with no success - I can't even implement a proper solution.

Can anyone suggest how I should start and what are the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried googling a bit for starter packs?

There are way more blogs about starting your own project than they were a few months ago, plus the official docs have bene updated (long time ago) to include a basic setup for Webpack users.

The following is my go to [starter kit](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack)

Here is another [seed project](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) from the Angular Class guys

If you find the two solutions above too confusing, just go ahead and use [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) this is by far the easiest solution

Also egghead just published a very good series on Angular 2.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a huge number of help docs on this topic online. If you haven't already, you'd have to learn more about API endpoints and how to implement them on the server side.

It doesn't matter which server side technology you are using. Whether it is .net, PHP, Node etc. Angular (or any other front-end JS framework for that matter) communicates with them via JSON objects wherein the data to be sent or received is first converted into a JSON object before being transmitted or received.

Same goes for the server side. Any data being sent or received by the server is interpreted as a JSON object first and then converted into the required datatype for further server side processing.

Answer (score -1):

You can do so using `yo generator`

I think the generator is called: `aspnet-spa`

It will provide you with angular, knockout options

Here is the official docs: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/yeoman.html